# What is the Vaisheshika view on meditation?

Tags: meditation, shad-darshana, vaisheshika, vaisheshika-sutra

What is the Vaisheshika view on meditation? Does it explicitly oppose it? Or does it recognize meditation as something that can be helpful? Or it did not bother to say anything about it. What exactly is the truth?

Answer (score 1):

According to the Vaisheshika school, liberation is achieved through the knowledge of six categories (Padartha).

> The highest good (Nihsreyasa or Moksa) results from the knowledge of the truth which springs from particular merit and is obtained by means of the similarity and dissimilarity of the categories (Padartha), substance (Dravya), attribute (Guna), action (Karma), generality (Samanya), particularity (Visesa) and combination (Samavaya). - Vaisheshika Sutra I.I.4

One specific category is the substance, and there are 10 types of substances (Dravya).

> Earth, water, light, air, ether, time, space, self, and mind - are the substances. - Vaisheshika Sutra I.I.5

**Self (Atma) is a specific type of substance, and it can be known by the mind (Manas) by meditation.** The ascetics who are engaged in meditation can know the self.

> Perceptual knowledge of self is made possible by particular conjunction (yoga) between the self and the mind. - Vaisheshika Sutra IX.I.11

The ascetic who is in course of union requires contemplation, but who is already united, does not need contemplation. So basically after describing the perception of the yogin who is in course of union, he describes that of the yogin who has attained union (samadhi). These yogins can transcend the senses in samadhi and they can also know the self.

> In those whose mind is not meditative, and in those whose meditation is consummated (samadhi) there is the perception of the soul. - Vaisheshika Sutra IX.I.13

Thus we see that mediation is a valid way (in fact the only way) to know Atma according to the Vaisheshika school.